# Sprite Kit, force stop on physics

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm creating an *ongoing learning project* (basically I code while learning to use the framework in hope it will be useful for me and for someone else) for Sprite Kit (you can find it [here](https://github.com/napolux/fallingpieces) if you are interested) but I'm facing some performance problems with my code.

The project puts cubes on the screen and make them falling. [Here's the class that creates the piece](https://github.com/napolux/fallingpieces/blob/master/fallingpieces/FLPPiece.m)

```
// The phisics for our falling piece:
// It will be a square, subject to gravity of 5: check common.h (9.8 is way too much for us)
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];
self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
self.physicsBody.mass = 100;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = piecesCollisionBitmask;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
```

and [here is the scene file with the loop](https://github.com/napolux/fallingpieces/blob/master/fallingpieces/FLPMyScene.m).

```
//schedule pieces
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
SKAction *pieceIsFalling = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    FLPPiece *piece = [[FLPPiece alloc] init];
    [self addChild:piece];
}];

SKAction *fallingPieces = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,pieceIsFalling]];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:fallingPieces]];
```

I suspect that physics is behind my frame rate drop. I would like to stop physics execution on node while keeping it on the screen as soon as it collides with something else.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: I can see that you still haven't implemented contact detection in your project. That will help, as it is triggered when two physicsBodies come into contact with each other. That will help you carry out such operations. This tutorial at raywendelich.com will help you set it up: http://www.raywenderlich.com/51108/build-spaceinvaders-in-spritekit-part-2-of-2

Comment: Thanks! I will implement it. I got how it works and that's what I need. But how can I stop physics run on a node after I detect the collision?

Comment: You can set it's physicsBody to nil, or set node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

Comment: Also, in your project, I noticed you initialise the explosion emitter in the init method and then hide it. This could be a reason for your framerate drop. I would suggest adding the SKEmitter onto the node at the point you want to 'unhide' it.

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve performance problems implementing the contact detection and removing the emitter (for now). BTW the detection is really poor... http://i58.tinypic.com/15wm7g9.png Here's my didBeginContact() https://github.com/napolux/fallingpieces/blob/043db0699ce6026a603a0bb1c197bb5355ab6c41/fallingpieces/FLPMyScene.m#L39

Comment: In a collision, the bodyA or bodyB can be any node... I have posted my revision of your -didBeginContact method in the answer.

Comment: Also, in what sense is the detection poor?

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I managed to avoid lateral collisions for the  cube. Plus, I'm adjusting blocks positioning after collision is detected (if pieces are one inside the other, they are put in correct position). Check here: https://github.com/napolux/fallingpieces/blob/d0a1ac7e1b5e5b39830ab59827c5ce660fb1937e/fallingpieces/FLPMyScene.m#L87